# Why boolean is set false at the beginning and is the code right?

Tags: java

i would like to know first why Boolean is set to be false at the beginning and the pre-last "else"  i ca not understand that condition that code is suppose to differentiate vowels from consonants  ??

https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/java-program-to-check-vowel-and-consonant-using-switch-case/

Comment: It is basic logic actually.  It starts false, and it is set to true in the `switch` statement whenever a vowel is seen.  Think it through.  "Hand execute" the program with a pencil and paper.  (It is possible to give a deeper mathematical explanation / proof, but it would go way over your head ... and probably mine too if it was rigorous!)

Comment: If I had to write code that way (multiple assignments to the same variable), I'd comment the first one `// hypothesis` or similar. Programming is a form of storytelling. This telling isn't very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the Code when you ask a Question and don't just put a link in here.

To answer your Question the Code is correct, just the 2nd ; in

```
boolean isVowel=false;;
```

isn't necessary. The boolean is set to false to Show that they assume by Default that the given char is no Vowel.

The switch basically checks if the given char is an a,e,i… and has to check for upper and lower case because they are treated different. If the given char Matches any of the given values the boolean is set to true because the char is a vowel.

The second last else Statement checks the UTF-16 values of the Alphabet, you can cast a char to an int which determines ist value in UTF-16 encoding for the lower cases it is 97-122 and for the upper cases their values are 65-90. If the int value of the char is not in this range the char is not in the Alphabet. You can refer to an ascii table to know which char is equivalent to which int.

Comment: The initialization is necessary because otherwise isVowel has an undefined value at the point where it is tested.

Comment: boolean are by Default false and i was refering to the the 2nd ';' which isn't necessary

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your sentence as saying the initialization was not needed, not the semicolon.  But booleans are not 'by default false' when the type is used for a local variable, as here.  [A local variable must be explicitly given a value before it is used - JLS 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Comment: Java (as well as .NET, JavaScript, VB4/5/6/A/Script, …) use the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set of char and string datatypes; not ASCII.